# Error: "Cannot instantiate firebase-storage - be sure to load firebase-app.js first"

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I have the following:

```
db.collection("users")
    .where("activated", "==", 0)
    .get()
    .then(snap => {
    snap.forEach(doc => {
        if (String(doc.data().profileURL) != String(defaultImageUrl)) {
            var r = document.getElementById('userTable').insertRow()
            r.insertCell(1).innerHTML = doc.data().age
            
            var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
            var temp_photo = storageRef.child('avatar/'+doc.data().profileURL+'/')
            temp_photo.getDownloadURL().then(downloadURL => {
                 console.log("log here -> " + downloadURL);
                var y = r.insertCell(2).innerHTML = '<img src="'+downloadURL+'" width="50" height="50" />';
            })
            }
        }
      }//closing braces might be off but the rest of the code works, just to this purpose
    });
});
```

All the data shows correctly, but the image doesn't show and the app crashes

> [Error] Error: Cannot instantiate firebase-storage - be sure to load
> firebase-app.js first.    (anonymous function)
> (firebase-storage.js:1:39246)     (anonymous function)
> (firebase-storage.js:1:165)   Global Code (firebase-storage.js:1:188)
> [Error] Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: firebase.storage is
> not a function. (In 'firebase.storage()', 'firebase.storage' is
> undefined)    (anonymous function) (toActivate.js:39)     (anonymous
> function) (firebase-firestore.js:1:278233)    (anonymous function)
> (firebase-firestore.js:1:64792)   (anonymous function)
> (firebase-firestore.js:1:58068)   (anonymous function)
> (firebase-firestore.js:1:58062)   (anonymous function)
> (firebase-firestore.js:1:58062)   (anonymous function)
> (firebase-firestore.js:1:58062)   (anonymous function)
> (firebase-firestore.js:1:64769)   (anonymous function)
> (firebase-firestore.js:1:278214)  (anonymous function)
> (toActivate.js:20)    promiseReactionJob

In my html i do have the storage script:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.5/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.5/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.3/firebase-storage.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The versions of your Firebase scripts need to all match.  Your firebase-storage does not match firebase-app.  According to the [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js), latest version is 7.23.0.